# asyncio socket for 127.0.0.1 vs 127.0.0.3

Tags: network-programming, python-asyncio

Not able to figure out what is wrong when I give address as 127.0.0.3(TimeoutError), whereas the following code works fine when the addr is 127.0.0.1(ConnectionRefusedError). Note that in both the cases, the server is not up.

Can anyone elaborate why different errors are being shown up here, and ConnectionResfusedError is quick, whereas the TimeoutError takes time.

```
import asyncio
async def handle_connection(addr, port, message):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(addr, port)

    print(f'Send: {message!r}')
    writer.write(message.encode())

    data = await reader.read(100)
    print(f'Received: {data.decode()!r}')

    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    addr = '127.0.0.3'
    port = 8888
    try:
        asyncio.run(handle_connection(addr, port, 'request'))
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Error: {err}'
```

Comment: I get 'connection refused' for both.

Comment: Thanks for checking it, To me seems like 127.0.0.3(TimeoutError) is blocked by firewall. Not sure how to check if this is the case.